# A direct proof for non-zero limit points of weighted backward shifts

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems

Fix a sequence $(w_1,w_2,\ldots)$ of positive reals such that the linear operator $T: \ell_2\to \ell_2$ given by
$$
T(x_1,x_2,x_3,....)=(w_2x_2,w_3x_3,\ldots) \text{ for all sequences in } \ell_2
$$
is well defined and continuous.

The following result has been shown [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/24716016.pdf?casa_token=zYCWQp-2Q80AAAAA:9ToAqMw-vtIYkg-k8j_5qPLjjHP5CdjtR9_2dpn-a3eenIMf30wMujCR-GBjWIWVkhDCvNj9HsFPl0YsLG_KrmzPn7uLrZtFjI5sZq4LHFMCTePlL9NR) (another proof [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.01641.pdf)):

> **Theorem.** Fix an operator $T$ as above such that there exists $x \in \ell_2$ for which $\{x,Tx, T^2x,\ldots\}$ has a non-zero limit point. Then there exists $y \in \ell_2$ such that  $\{y, Ty, T^2y, \ldots \}$ is dense in $\ell_2$.

However, the proofs rely on known characterizations of the required property (called hypercyclicity) of these type of operators (called weighted backward shifts).

Here I am asking something weaker: is it possible to find a *direct* proof of the following claim?

> **Weak Theorem.** Fix an operator $T$ as above such that there exists $x \in \ell_2$ for which $\{x,Tx, T^2x,\ldots\}$ has a non-zero limit point. Then for each non-empty open set $U\subseteq \ell_2$ there exists a sequence $y$ such that $\{y,Ty,T^2y, \ldots\}$ has a limit point in $U$.

Comment: What do you mean by *a direct proof*? The hypercyclicity criterion is a quick application of Baire's theorem. Do you want to avoid Baire?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth "Direct" cannot be defined precisely, you are right. Anyway, to answer your question, Baire's theorem is fine